# Communication Spring MVC and Socket Server

Tags: spring-mvc, serversocket

I have an Spring MVC application in Tomcat and a Desktop Server Socket App, I would like to make requests from the Spring MVC app to the Server Socket. I would like your advise which technology I shall use, to address my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need used the Spring Web socket programming. I have example for Server to Client (Browser) communication. Please take a look that will be help you also.

https://github.com/iotasol/AngularJs-and-Websocket-with-java-spring